# MySQL fail after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, dpkg, mysql

I used Ubuntu 18.04 with LAMP, Python, Dockers, etc. Once, I received a message, that my laptop ready to upgrade, I accepted and the updating process starts. On the 50% of process, I received a message, that something went wrong and Ubuntu stop to upgrade. During rebooting I saw the message:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

So I tried to know the status of my MySQL: `systemctl status mysql.service` and have got result:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-11-29 10:46:34 EET; 6h ago

лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC mysql-systemd-start[1635]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips o>
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC mysql-systemd-start[1635]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
лис 29 10:46:34 it-HP-250-G7-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Next I tried to fix all packages: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` but in the final command line see next warning:

```
2020-11-29T15:12:34.680279Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,N
O_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2020-11-29T15:12:34.696826Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Next i tried fix all installations: `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`, nothing helps me. I do not want to delete MySQL because I have actual DataBaces, it is important for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67747756/6652972

> Thank you @FANO_FN. This was the line in
> `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` which needed to be corrected.
> mysql8 doesn't have the value of NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)
> anymore. So, I removed that from the list of values and it started
> working.
>
> The final values look like below:
>
> `sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

The reason is that `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` is no longer part of mysql8.